# Randomly generated number array

Tags: java

How do I create a random number array in Java of sizes 100, 200, 300, etc. for this method?

```
    public static void insertionSort(int[] arr){
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
            int current = arr[i];
            int k;
            for(k = i - 1; k >= 0 && arr[k] > current; k--){
                arr[k + 1] = arr[k];
            }
            arr[k + 1] = current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Write some code yourself and ask a *specific* question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random number array sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922506/random-number-array-sorting)

Comment: Look up `Math.random()`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you are wanting to create an array of random numbers to then pass into the method you posted. If that is the case, you can use the following to create an array, and then change the size in accordance with your needs.

```
int[] arr = new int[100];

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = (Math.random() * 100);
}
```

This will fill each index of your array with a random number < '100'.

Comment: you don't need `arr.length-1`

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see, you want to create an array of integers. You have to iterate the step to continually generate random numbers. This code will do.

```
int[] array = new int[100];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    array[i] = new Random().nextInt(100);
    // this will generate not more than 100 integers
}

// show sorted result
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```